# Use alias with conditional operator in a single statement?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

When using conditional operator to return value from two optional methods I often wonder if can use alias to substitute one of the methods and use that alias in the options part of the statement. For example, I would write this:

```
Row temp; 
nextRow = (temp = getNextRow(nextRow)) == null ? createRowBelow(nextRow) : temp;
```

in place of this:

```
nextRow = getNextRow(nextRow) == null ? createRowBelow(nextRow) : getNextRow(nextRow);
```

But what frustrates me is that I have to declare the variable in a separate line, which kinda blemish the one-line beauty of this statement. So is there a way to use alias and keep it one-line? Besides, I'm not really sure if the first one is **actually** more efficient than the second, albeit `getNextRow()` is called only once.

Comment: Ignore "one line beauty". It clouds your judgement and makes you waste time pursuing "succinct" code. Explicitness is underrated.

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm not particularly pursuing succinctness, but since it's an integrated feature of Java I think it can be used extensively, and indeed it saves time and work, and also I don't find it less explicit than other approaches.

Comment: The worst thing you have to fear from the "extra" line is a sprained finger from all that typing. Take @Carcigenicate's advice and don't get caught up in succinctness. Take it from someone whose largest proportion of time in his long career has been maintaining code, succinctness impedes readability more often than not. The advantage of the `temp` approach isn't succinctness, it's avoiding two calls to a method, important if the method has side effects. It also supports debugging. You should make that variable `final`. Now put aside your prejudice and start thinking like an engineer.

Comment: And that isn't an "alias".